# SQL time column does not sort in ascending order

Tags: mysql, sql, time, sql-order-by

I was having some trouble when trying to write an SQLstatement which sorted by time column which is in varchar format in ascending order. Here is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT mrtpopTime, mrtpopAmt
FROM tm_mrtpop
WHERE mrtpopName = ''
ORDER BY mrtpopTime
```

And I am getting these results:

[image]

As you can see from the picture, it was sorted by character by character. Is there anyway to sort it like:

```
0:00, 1:00, 2:00, 3:00 all the way to 23:00
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert varchar time column to a `time` (or dummy date plus time) and order by that:

```
SELECT mrtpopTime, mrtpopAmt
FROM tm_mrtpop
WHERE mrtpopName = ''
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(mrtpopTime, '%H:%i')
```

Answer (score 2):

As the mrtpopTime is in varchar it won't sort. Hence cast it into float and order by

```
SELECT  mrtpopTime, mrtpopAmt
FROM tm_mrtpop
WHERE mrtpopName = ''
ORDER BY 'cast(mrtpopTime as float) time'
```