# SQL sum(time) as time column does not sort in ASC and DESC order

Tags: mysql, time

I have been trying to sort the result of my SQL query but it's not working properly,
I have tried other solutions, but not worked, reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873187/sql-time-column-does-not-sort-in-ascending-order)

My Query

```
SELECT tournament_entry.TE_club, MAX(tournament_entry.TE_pegion) As TE_pegion, 
       concat(
       floor(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(tournament_entry.TE_flytime))/3600),':',
       floor(SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(tournament_entry.TE_flytime))/60)%60,':',
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(tournament_entry.TE_flytime))%60) as TE_flytime
  FROM tournament_entry  
  WHERE  tournament_entry.TE_tournament = '$Tname'  
  GROUP BY TE_club 
  ORDER BY TE_flytime DESC
```

Point 1, I have used CONCAT(), the reason to display the sum of time greater than 838:59:59 reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733148/surpassing-mysqls-time-value-limit-of-8385959)

Step 1 followed,

```
ORDER BY TE_flytime ASC
```

results, which is not correct

[image]

Step 2 followed,

```
ORDER BY TE_flytime DESC
```

results, not correct, in this way it takes results greater than 1000 to the bottom (last), 
maybe if there is any logic or way to use and it will sort it properly.

[image]

Step 3 followed,

```
ORDER BY 'cast(TE_flytime as float) time'
```

results, not correct, mixed up all results.  reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873187/sql-time-column-does-not-sort-in-ascending-order)

[image]

NOTE: I want to sort it  in a way that it displays the greatest result on top and so on

e.g

```
1034:46:0
1027:4:0
965:37:0
809:11:0
```

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511882/sorting-by-date-time-in-descending-order

Comment: What version of MySQL are you on?

Comment: Why are you sorting only by one attribute? Use three attributes and it will work as you want.

Comment: @Martin Server version: 10.3.23-MariaDB, and i have tried the above-mentioned link nothing helped

Comment: @XraySensei cos I don't need to display extra fields on result and result is depended on Total Fly Time (TE_flytime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculated column `TE_flytime` is a string so if you sort by that column the sorting will be alphabetical.
You can order by the total number of seconds:

```
ORDER BY SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(tournament_entry.TE_flytime)) DESC
```